# Cannot Find Path Specified Creating File Despite Existing Parent Directory

Tags: java, file, zip

I am trying to export zip files to a directory and running into an IOException stating that the file path cannot be found. I am aware that this means that the parent directory does not exist usually, however debugging the line where the file is being written file.getParentFile().exists() returns true, so this is not my issue. To further complicate matters, this only occurs for approximately half of the files written. It is always the same files that fail when unzipping via java, but unzipping them via windows always successfully works.

Here is the code I am using:

```
ZipInputStream zis =
                new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(zipFile));
ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();

while (ze != null) {
    String fileName = ze.getName();
    File newFile = new File(outputFolder + File.separator + fileName);
    if(!newFile.isDirectory()) {
        newFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile); //Exception occurs here
        //newFile.getParentFile().exists() returns true 
        //copying the path for newFile.getParentFile() into my file browser leads me to a valid, existing folder
        //I have tried newFile.createNewFile() and that errors with a similar exception

        int len;
        while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        fos.close();
        results.add(new Foo());
    }
    ze = zis.getNextEntry();
}
```

Example exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\foo\foo\foo\foo\foo\foo\foo.pdf (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Some more notes about the system: the file system is a remote network drive, the system is running windows, and the account has full write access to the drive. I have also verified that naming a file foo.pdf (copy and pasting the name of the file intended to be written) does not cause any issue either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that zip files can have trailing spaces in their paths. For example, "Test whatever .zip" could be the file name so java sees the folder as "/Test whatever /" and it tries to create that folder. Windows tells java that it succeeded, but really it created a folder at "/Test Whatever/". When dealing with folders, the file IO has no issue with this, but when writing files, it completely bombs as it's looking for the path explicitly. It does not truncate the extra white space the same way it does when dealing with folders, as you would expect.

Here is the code I used to resolve it:

```
String path = (outputFolder + File.separator + fileName).replace(" ", "");

File newFile = new File(path);
```